# Difference between hvplot and holoplot

Tags: python, plot, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

So for a while now I have been migrating from Matplotlib to holoviews for my plotting needs, and mostly enjoying what I have experienced. Then i notice hvplot, which seems to make the holviews workflow way easier, by tying it closer together with Pandas. All good so far. But now I discover holoplot, which seems to do the same thing? I am quite confused, so hopefully someone could please try to explain to me the difference between hvplot and holoplot. Please...

Kind regards,
Rasmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HoloPlot](https://pypi.org/project/holoplot/) was the predecessor of hvPlot, even the logo is the same :)
I think it got renamed [hvPlot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/index.html) in later versions.
It was developed by exactly the same developers.

**So for high-level plotting use hvPlot.**

https://hvplot.holoviz.org/index.html

Comment: Right -- we originally chose the name holoplot but changed it on the advice of our lawyers, because of the company you can find at holoplot.com ; they work in a very different field but also deal with images so legally there could have been some overlap.